# wrong permissions on server after upgrade to new OS on LAMP server

Tags: server, permissions, lamp

after our LAMP server upgraded the OS I am finding that the permissions are wrong on the server, and it cannot display the file (404 error), until I change the permissions.

It was working fine before this upgrade. I have to change the permissions from "rwx" to "rw-" on every file. I use Krusader for FTP.

Is there some solution, so that I don't have to adjust each file? I have a website with over 400 pages, so it is very tedious.

Regards, Adrian

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specifics, but I suspect that the problem might have been caused by umask being set to the wrong value during the upgrade.
If all you need to do is change the permissions on many webpages, it's pretty easy on the *nix command line.

First, back up everything. Then, from a *nix shell command, cd into the directory that holds all the webpages. Note: If the directory holds other files in addition to the webpages whose permissions you want to change, the following command will change their permissions, too. In that case, you'll have to figure out a regular expression to segregate them when running the command. The following command will change ALL files in the current directory to have read and write permission for the owner, and read-only permission for everyone else:

```
$ chmod 644 *
```

This will change the permissions of ALL files to rw-r--r--.
If you have directories, you'll probably want them to have permissions 755 (rwxr-xr-x) rather than 644.

The three-digit number provides the permissions for owner, group, and world, respectively:

```
7 = read, write, and execute
6 = read and write
5 = read and execute
4 = read only
3 = write and execute (you don't want this)
2 = write only (you don't want this)
1 = execute only (you don't want this)
```

If you have to upload them via FTP, then I suggest you download them all to a *nix system and run the command on your local copy, and then re-upload them.
If you provide more detail, I can provide a more detailed answer.
Remember to back everything up first.